# dojox.mobile.ListItem - passing parameter with click/touch

Tags: javascript, list, mobile, dojo

I have this code:

```
<ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList">

  <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='moveTo:"places_aroud_me_view",callback: set_placeTypeAroundMe_calback("park"),transition:"slide"'>Park</li>

  <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='moveTo:"places_aroud_me_view",callback: set_placeTypeAroundMe_calback("art"),transition:"slide"'>Art</li>

</ul>
```

As you see calback is used and it refers to specyfic function with parameter. Basicly it doesn't work becouse the code always launches all the functions in all calbacks (console log will display all calls one after another).

If I do this:

```
<li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='moveTo:"places_aroud_me_view",callback: set_placeTypeAroundMe_calback,transition:"slide"'>Park</li>
```

The calback work just fine. One click -> one calback.

So.... how can I pass parameter to the js function in calback?
What I want to do is set a global js variable value so in next dojo mobile view (after click) I had access to this variable (and use it for something, check place type here).

If passing parameter this way is not possible, then maybe anyone know other way to pass variable from one dojo mobile view to another (preferably using lists)?

Thank in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
<li id="park" class="places_around_me_list" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='moveTo:"places_aroud_me_view",transition:"slide"'>Park</li>

<li id="art" class="places_around_me_list" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='moveTo:"places_aroud_me_view",transition:"slide"'>Art</li>


require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/query", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/domReady"], function(dom, dquery, on, domAttr){
    node = dquery(".places_around_me_list");
    on(node, "touchstart", function(e){
        id = domAttr.get(this, "id");
        //console.log("Clicked id:" + id);
        set_placeTypeAroundMe_reference(id);
    });     
});
```

Notice that on desktop you need to attach event to "click", while on the mobile this solution will have same effect as "callback" I mentioned below (always last will run...). Also on mobile sth like alert will block working of dojo mobile "moveTo"... so basicly solution is not perfect. Any alternatives?

EDIT:
Ok, here is a code that will work on the click an mobile too. It seems to be fully stable:

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/query", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/domReady"], function(dom, dquery, on, domAttr){
    node = dquery(".places_around_me_list");
    dquery(".places_around_me_list").forEach(function(item){
        on(item, "click", function(e){
        id = domAttr.get(item, "id");
        set_placeTypeAroundMe_reference(id);
        });
    });     
});
```

EDIT2: Sometimes in dojo mobile you might get this bug -> Before you take away you finger from touchscreen you may launch completelly unwanted action or responce (for example one list is replaced with new one before you take your finger away). This should help:

```
on(item, touch.release, function(e){...}
```

Comment: don't use touchstart event for this purpose, it will cause unwanted "clicks" each time you try to scroll the list

Comment: and second: iterate on dquery result nodes, with e.g. node.forEach(function(item){on.(item,"click"....  use "item" instead of "this"

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I didn't see your additional comment. Yes you are right.

Comment: Yep. touch.release hs same problem as touchstart witch scrolling, but simple clik works just fine in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

you could have a look at one of Dojo Mobile Showcase's examples:
http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileCharting/demo.html
Soruces are compressed a bit so they won't give you the clear picture.
Anyway...
Looks quite similar to your setup. List view with multiple li-s with one destination view.

You could either create listitem elements programatically (to attach event on creation) or simply get them later by adding id attributes to them (or using dojo's query functionality).

```
function something(item){
     require(["dojo/dom-attr"], function(domAttr){
          var data = domAttr.get(item,"customattribute");//use your data
          //work with destination view
     });
}

require(["dojo/dom","dojo/on"], function(dom,on){ 
    var item = dom.byId("listitem1");
    on(item,"click", something(item));
});
```

Thats just a general idea, you could extend it with dojo/query to fetch all of the listitems at once and extend the listitems with custom attributes containing your data.
e.g.

```
<li customattribute="data" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" ...
```

Comment: Good idea. It worked but it's a litle bit "heywire" - sometimes doesn't do what it suppoused to do, so if anyone has better alternative it would be nice too. I will present code below.